# Left function VBA

Tags: vba, excel, search, formula, userform

Hi to Any and all willing to assist.

I appear to be having issues with the left function in VBA. I am looking to search using a reference number and then the userform will pull through data that is stored within a table. In 1 section of the userform I have 4 text boxes looking to pull through different sections of 1 cell. The trouble is that I am getting "FO" for the answer on this for every reference which is actually looking at the fo within my code please see below.

```
    Private Sub Find_Click()

    Dim searchRange As Range
    Dim foundCell As Range
    Dim mysearch As String

    mysearch = Me.Search.Value

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master Data")
        Set searchRange = .Range("A2", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With

    Set foundCell = searchRange.Find(what:=mysearch, Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
        Me.BDM.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 6).Value
        Me.Mrch.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 7).Value
        Me.EUs.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 8).Value
        Me.Pr.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 10).Value
        Me.Qty.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 11).Value
        Me.RsnCd.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 12).Value
        Me.ReOrCd.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 13).Value
        Me.Tot.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 5).Value
        Me.V.Value = Me.Total.Value / 1.2
        Me.VT.Value = Me.Total.Value - Me.Value.Value
        Me.Req.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 17).Value
        Me.Appl.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 18).Value
        Me.Line1.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 19).Value
        Me.Line2.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 20).Value
        Me.Ci.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 21).Value
        Me.Poe.Value = foundCell.Offset(0, 22).Value
        Me.SC1.Value = Left(foundCell.Offset(0, 23).Value, 2)
'this is where in code I am receiving fo from the foundcell everytime       
    Else
         MsgBox "ID does not exist."
    End If

    End Sub
```

I always thought the left in vba worked the same as excel which is `left(a2, 2)` for example

Comment: Can you give an example of the entire value of `foundCell.Offset(0, 23).Value`?

Comment: @steenbergh It differs but it is always 10 characters long..... so if I was to enter a reference number say 105763 it should be giving =Left(*, 2) of GCA1212BCF. If that makes sense?

Comment: There shouldnt be any reason why the code isnt working from looking at it. The only way it would be returning "fo" on foundcell is if you had double quotes around "foundcell.Offset..." or if "FO" was within the cell. Try adding a breakpoint on that line and using "Debug.Print" in the immediate window to check the value of foundcell.Offset(0, 23).Value

Comment: @MBrann So you would expect to see 'GC', but you get 'FO', right? Could it be that there is actually a code starting with 'FO' here? Then the error would be in another part of the code, whereit retrieves something from the database that you're not expecting...

Comment: @steenbergh yes that is correct it should be returning 'GC' in this case. However, there are no codes starting with FO apart from 'fo'undCell. Brandon mentioned this should only be occuring when in placed in speech quotes "foundcell.offset..." Thanks for your suggestions guys please keep them coming I am at a loss it seems

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, the classic exit and restart appears to have fixed the issue although I am not sure why still. Leaving the workbook and re-opening appears to have fixed the issue. Sorry to have wasted anyones time

Answer (score 0):

Unsure why but simply restarting excel resolved the issue and no issue with code